# How to get list of all running processes in Linux more than 15 minutes and send email those processes to user

Tags: linux, bash

I need to build a bash script,

1. to get list of all running processes in linux which are more than 15 mins
2. exclude one process (cdfa)
3. send email those process list to user (test@mail.com)

Answer (score 2):

1. Get processes running for a duration: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/531040
2. Remove `cdfa` using `grep -v`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/354993
3. Send email using a command line: https://serverfault.com/questions/370935

```sh
set -e # instruct this script to stop on first error

# Specify process columns, but filter those where second column > 900 seconds and removing "cdfa"
processes=$(ps -e -o "pid,etimes,command=" | awk '{if($2>900) print $3}' | grep -v cdfa)

echo "Found $(echo "$processes" | wc -l) matching processes"

# Create a temporary file with the results in email format
echo -e "Subject: Processes running for 15 minutes\n" > "/tmp/$$.mail"
echo "$processes" >> "/tmp/$$.mail"

echo "Writing email /tmp/$$.mail"

# Uncomment to display the processes
# cat "/tmp/$$.mail"

# Send an email using the temporary file
echo "Sending email /tmp/$$.mail"
sendmail "test@mail.com" < "/tmp/$$.mail"

# Cleanup the temporary file
rm "/tmp/$$.mail"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @tresf, ps -e -o "pid,etimes,command" | awk '{if($2>900) print $3}' print is not giving the complete line (ex: "nginx: worker process" from this result is coming "nginx" only), also i want to get the process list sending as attachment in email)

Comment: @Ravi tresf gave you more than enough information to make your own script, and went as far ahead to giving you a featured implementation. S.O. is for learning exchanging information, but your request is alike asking for a free coding service. Please try to play with what tresf showed you, make your own adjustments. And if you have another issue, post a new specific question. Asking for implementations is inappropriate.

Comment: @Ravi it's actually quite hard to get all the information after `$3` due to the delimiters that `awk` uses being part of the process.  A quick hack is to add more values, but this won't scale.  If it's good enough for you, can you try `'{if($2>900) print $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $6 " " $7 " "}'`